# I keep getting confusing errors using p5 in processing

Tags: javascript

SyntaxError: Expected ; but found hr. I keep getting this message even when the "hr" part is gone. I'm totally lost. Trying to make a clock. The comments were where I had successfully made a text clock.

```
function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
}

function draw() {
  background();
  let hr = hour();
  let mn = minute();
  let sc = second();

  strokeWeight(4);
  stroke(255);
  noFill();
  ellipse(200, 200, 300, 300);



//  fill(255);
//  noStroke();
//  text(hr + ':' + mn + ':' + sc, 10, 200);
}
```

Comment: "Doctor, you've got to help me. Something hurts."

Comment: How are we supposed to help you? We have nothing to go on here

Comment: Okay sorry I tried posting a picture on here but it wouldn't let me. I have:

Comment: @user8693619 you have *what*?

Comment: function setup() {

Comment: Im sorry I keep hitting the post button hang on

Comment: Code is not a picture. It's text, typed in on a keyboard. Images of text are useless. If you want help with your code, [edit] your question and add the code there, as text, properly formatted as code. For formatting help, click the **?** button at the top right of the area where you're asking your question. When you make that [edit], also include the **specific information** about the error you're getting (which means the **exact** error message).

Comment: function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
}

function draw() {
  background();
  let hr = hour();
  let mn = minute();
  let sc = second();
  
  strokeWeight(4);
  stroke(255);
  noFill();
  ellipse(200, 200, 300, 300);
  
  
  
//  fill(255);
//  noStroke();
//  text(hr + ':' + mn + ':' + sc, 10, 200);
}

Comment: this is my first post on here, sorry. I keep messing up

Comment: Okay I put the code in. Sorry, just getting used to this site.

Comment: What error message are you getting?

Comment: SyntaxError: Expected ; but found hr

Answer (score 1):

[`background` requires an argument](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/background). Try

```
 background(0);
```

Comment: It gave me the same error message with the background 0

Comment: works for me: https://alpha.editor.p5js.org/greggman/sketches/HkBobq2jZ

Comment: Wow! It worked after I restarted processing and pasted the code back in! Thanks!